# invalid syntax while reading multiple txt files

Tags: machine-learning

Everyone
I am facing problem you can see it in pic attached. when i run it on Google Colab it works perfetly and when trying to run it in local it encounter the syntax error. how it will be corrected any one how to solve it, Thanks. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awTCs.png)

Comment: Try to enter the absolute or relative path of the file

Comment: Please share the text of your code and syntax error rather than an image. Text is more easily searchable and can be copy/pasted to help reproduce the error. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask